# How can I embed file into an excel spreadsheet cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Does anyone know of a way to embed a PDF, JPG, Word file, or Outlook email into an Excel cell?

I am entering data into cells and want to link them to specific documents and to save them getting lost.

Comment: Are you asking if you can attach word docs, .eml etc in excel such that you send the excel file and everything stays on it for whoever receives it?

Comment: yes you have hit it on the nail.. i enter lots of data but with each entry want to put a document against it, and all saved in one file no matter how big the file.. so its easy to find related documentation

Comment: And why are you using excel, as opposed to sharepoint or another kms?

Comment: I am not familiar with any other programme is there one that does the same as excel as a spreadsheet but also does dragdrop? I do not know what sharepoint is sorry to sound so thick..

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is - what are you trying to accomplish, in the long run? This won't be very scalable. So if you want to send a couple pictures in a sheet, no problem. If you want to put links in to network locations with data, sure. If you need it all attached, it will become unwieldy pretty quickly.

Comment: the combined file needs to be in one so that nothing gets lost and it can be easily copied via usb stick etcc from computer to computer

Comment: okay well to cut a long story short. I am a trainee accountant. using excel for accounting. what i am trying to achieve is for my clients to put some basic info into a spreadsheet, just date, description, and category and prices with and without vat, and then beside it a copy of the invoice dragged and dropped, so that they can send me by email or usb one file with everything linked together this is only for small firms who may send two hundred or less entries each time by email or usb.. so the actual files will not get too big and what i had hoped click on cell and file would open

Comment: What version of excel?

Comment: Well, I don't really have a solution for you, but I recommend against excel. At best it will become too unwieldy to use. At worst, it will begin corrupting the spreadsheet data. Maybe a better idea would be to go to softwarerecs.se and see if they know of anything.

Comment: A note on vocabulary: "embed" means to make a copy of one file and insert it into another file. This gives you a self-contained file (think of an anthology) that can grow very large (if you embed multiple other files into it). "link" means to store the ***name*** of one file in another, like a paper with a bibliography or a web page with external links. This avoids the bloat problem, but it means that the file (containing links) is crippled if the other files aren't around. You seem to be talking about embedding. If you _are_ talking about embedding, don't say "I ... want to link them ...".

Comment: yes g-man you are right it should have been embed not link.. apologies

Comment: 2013 via university 365 subscription

Answer (score 3):

Tested in excel 2007
Go to Insert -> Object -> "Create from file" tab -> browse to the file -> hit OK

Source
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/insert-attachment-excel-spreadsheet-76201.html

EDIT:
The negative side to this is that anything you embed will be included in the file, thus making the excel file quite large.

Comment: The questions asks ** embed into the cell** not into the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to lock an embedded file in excel is to first attach the file as an object in the spreadsheet.  Use "insert object" and you can either insert a file or view as an icon.  THen move the object wherever you want it.

Then right click on the on the object and select format object.  Make sure that "locked" is selected.  excel will then display the object on the selected cell and move it as the cell is moved by inserting extra cells etc.

I use this because I have a lot of rental properties and make up a monthly statement before I fill out the schedule E's.  I attach invoices to cells on the line items to which they refer.